# If condition check in linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Below are the linq query. Here I want to add one condition .
Condition : **If** : Firstname is not empty then select list 
                 where  (d=>d.firstname=="Firstname")
            **else**: select all list without condition

```
function Ponits(string Firstname)
{

     pointsCore.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.Events).Select(e => new
     {
            e.Firstname,
            e.Surname,
            e.EntityNumber,
            e.Eventdate
     }).ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Two options:

First, optionally use `Where`:

```
var events = pointsCore.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.Events);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
{
    events = events.Where(e => e.Firstname == firstName);
}
var result = events.Select(e => new { ... });
```

Second: make your `Where` clause check `firstName`:

```
var events = pointsCore.Categories.SelectMany(c => c.Events);
                       .Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ||
                                   e.Firstname == firstName)
                       .Select(e => new { ... });
```

Note that due to the lazy evaluation in LINQ, the first option *won't* involve fetching all the values and then querying; you're still just building up a query.

Answer (score 2):

```
.Where(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Firstname) || d.firstname==Firstname)
```